# What would be a proper reaction to the question: "Can you come over?" or how do you say "Coming" in Latin?

Tags: idiom, verbs

In a comment to [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/can-a-gerund-stand-alone) question, JoonasIlmavirta suggests a spin-off question.
I have had this question simmering for quite some time, but this is a nice incentive.

Consider the following cross-language table of a question and an answer.

| Language | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EN | Can you come over? | Coming! |
| NL | Kom je even hier? | Ik kom! |
| DE | Kannst Du mal hier kommen? | Ich komme! |
| FR | Tu peux venir ici? | J'arrive! |
| IT | Puoi venire qui? | Arrivo! |

*The answers are given according to the perspective of the one who asks*.

| Language | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ES | ¿Puedes venir aquí? | ¡Voy! |
| PT | Podes vir aquí? | Vou! |

*The answers are given according to the perspective of the one who answers*.

*What happens in Latin?*

**Huc venis?**   **Venio / Eo (?)**

Comment: I know there is a table facility, but when I tried to use it, it was displayed all-right in the preview, but not after saving. Feel free to reformat...

Comment: I converted to table formatting. It looks good to me, but let me know if it still looks wonky to you.

Comment: This was not the question, but the request should rather be *veni huc, veni ad me, accede huc*, etc.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel: Of course! I should have realised, knowing that the German translation for "Hinc equitavit" (Carmina Burana) is "Der ist geritten hinnen". Changed accordingly. But why the imperative?

Answer (score 3):

The phenomena you see in English, Dutch, German, French, and Italian are called *deictic projection*, where the speaker projects themself to the place previously referenced (the *deixis*), speaking as if from there.

According to the Oxford Latin Dictionary, *Venio!* would fit fine here:

> expr. movement to a place where the speaker is, or visualizes himself as being...

As for whether or not *ire* fits here as well, it doesn't seem to. It can mean come or go "in certain contexts". I think that's primarily due to English, not Latin. That is to say, if *ire* is translated as "come", it isn't because of the deictic projection that *venire* has, but rather because it happens to overlap where we in English would say "come" instead of "go".

Because of the fact that *venire* can be used for the place one anticipates going, I find it unlikely that *ire* would be used instead, unless to say "I'm heading out" or "I'm going", which is a little different from "I'm coming", giving information about how far you are in coming, not whether or not you're coming.